# Vuejs @input="function" is not working but @input="() => do something" is working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I don't understand why it is working when I am passing an anonymous function to the @input field of my html input component, but it is not working when i am calling instead a real function with the exact same code inside. Here is the code when it is not working:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const text = ref('')
const numberChar = ref(0)
const numberWords = ref(0)

function count() {
    numberChar = text.length
    numberWords = text.split(' ').filter((e) => e != '').length
}

</script>

<template>

<div class="box">
<input v-model="text" placeholder="Write here" @input="count"/>
 <p>
     Text : {{text}} <br>
     Characters : {{numberChar}} <br>
     Words : {{numberWords}}
 </p>
</div>

</template>
```

but when I am simply putting this :

```
<input v-model="text" placeholder="Write here" @input="() => numberChar = text.length"/>
```

the numberChar value is correcttly modified and displayed.
I am starting Vuejs so I am missing something but it's been an hour I am struggling with this...

Comment: any errorin console?

Comment: vue3? (you should tag your question with appropriate vue version tags, as stated in the vue.js tag) you want `numberChar.value = text.value.length` etc - read the documentation on how refs work in `<script setup>`

Comment: Pls give an [appropriate title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648) for your question.

Comment: @ArchitGargi Please explain why you think the title is not adhering to the linked article.

Comment: @RashadSaleh There is a point in my linked article about the title being in question format. Is it in this one?

Comment: @ArchitGargi Yes I believe so. However for me at least I didn't find it a problem. I cannot tell you whether the title should be rephrased or not.

Comment: @RashadSaleh According to me if it is in question format then it’s easier to understand and faster to read than this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, I managed to correct this issue. The problem was I wrote in my function

```
numberChar = text.length
```

instead of

```
numberChar.value = text.value.length
```

What is strange is that in my anonymous function it was working without the `.value` and I don't know why. In the tutorial here : https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-4 they are using it the way I tried to use it. And they said in the tutorial too that `.value` is not necessary because it is implicit if nothing is specified ?

To those of you saying the tag and title of my question were not correct, i'll try to do it better for the next time, thanks. (it is my first post on stackoverflow)

Thanks :)

Comment: You can still edit the question to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at: https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles

What you need to do is make `count` visible in your component.
Something like:

```
<script setup>
  ... 
  export default {
    methods: {
      count() {
        // Your code here.
      }
    }
  }

</script>

<template>

<div class="box">
  <input placeholder="Write here" @input="count"/>
  ...
</div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, if you would have press F12 and take a closer look into the console, you would see that your error occurs inside your count function. So the function itself is already called

Also you need to access your values with `.value`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const text = ref('')
const numberChar = ref(0)
const numberWords = ref(0)

function count() {
    numberChar.value = text.value.length
    numberWords.value = text.value.split(' ').filter((e) => e != '').length
}

</script>
```